# R won't let me define vector in data frame in list as POSIXct

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and have written my first script to handle some data from transducers. The script I wrote is pretty rough, but it works. Now I'm trying to clean it up.

The script I wrote makes a data frame for each transducer I have. I'm trying to replace that setup with a list of data frames, such that I can loop operations more easily. Currently my script runs each each 'command' or 'calculation' for each transducer (and therefore dataframe) seperately.... it's a lot of redundant code.

Here's where I'm stuck... my script used to run like this:

```
baro_data_temp <- read.csv(paste(file_subdir,"Barometr",file_append,file_type, sep=""), 
                header=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)

colnames(baro_data_temp) <- c('date', 'measurement')

baro_data_temp$date <-as.POSIXct(baro_data_temp$date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

These actions would be performed for each transducers (and therefore each .csv file). Defining the date columns as POSIXct works, but I get the errors about no timezone. That doesn't bother me; the timezone is irrelevant.

I've rewritten this part of my script like this:

```
data_import <- list()

for (i in seq_along(files_names)) {
data_import[[i]] <- read.csv(file = files_names[i], header=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
colnames(data_import[[i]]) <- c('date', 'measurement')
data_import[[i]]["date"] <- as.POSIXct(data_import[[i]]["date"],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
}

names(data_import) <- frames_names
```

Now I get an error that says

> "Error in as.POSIXct.default(data_import[[i]]["date"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):do not know how to convert 'data_import[[i]]["date"]' to class “POSIXct””

I can't figure out what is wrong.....

Comment: Try `data_import[[i]][["date"]]` instead.

Comment: Print files_names[i] then Check your data carefully

Comment: data_import[[i]][["date"]] worked

Comment: I'm still getting used to the double brackets in R. It seems that data_import[[i]]["date"] yields a data frame... I find that counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this issue, here is the answer.

data_import[[i]]["date"] yields a data frame. data_import[[i]][["date"]] yields a vector which resolved the issue at hand. data_import[[i]]$date also yields a vector and therefore also works.